# rails admin undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting an error message when I try to go inside the admin dashboard by the rails_admin gem.

Error

```
undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass
```

This is the whole code

```
          klass.setup if klass.respond_to? :setup
          @authorize = proc do
            @authorization_adapter = klass.new(*([self] + args).compact)
          end
        elsif block
          @authorize = block
```

It is pointing to this spot

```
            @authorization_adapter = klass.new(*([self] + args).compact)
```

I don't know why this happening because I did not touch anything from the rails admin

Comment: The message is telling you that your class `klass` is equal to nill or is not initiated.

Comment: @YLim : To elaborat a bit on the correct answer given by Kamal Panhwar: When you run the assignment to `@authorize`, the `proc` object is basically a closure and gets bound to the value `klass` had at that time. Hence the real problem doesn't stem from calling the proc, but is already present at the time `@authorize`  is initialized. `klass` must have been `nil` at this time already.

Comment: Please provide more context. No one will be able to provide any more useful answer than "`klass` is `nil`. That's what the error says.", unless you show more information about what this code is trying to do. What is `klass` supposed to be?

Answer (score 3):

To anyone who is scratching their head over this issue and stumbled upon this thread, on `/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb` try replacing

```
config.authorize_with :cancan
```

with

```
config.authorize_with :cancancan
```